# Adding new String resource to multiple (localized) strings.xml files in Android app

Tags: android, resources, localization, adt

I have an app with support for several different languages.
Now lets say I want to add a new feature, which will usually will require new string resources to be added.

What is the (Or is there) way to add new string resources that will be added automatically to all the localization strings files?  (Means i'll just need to translate the **content** of the string and not to create new one with the same key for each localization file)
Because it dosen't make any sense to copy-paste it manually when you have a lot of localization files...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow Android localization rules, there isin't any other way other than manually adding to each language strings.xml file. You can script this but then you will have to write the script. So, my suggestion is to bite the bullet and do it.

As you said if there are a lot of files, then scripting it is best way, even then you may have to manually add the localized string values to each file.

Comment: I dont mind creating new string.xml *file* because it is done once per language.  
But to manually add new string to each file every time i need to add a string is a sirious pain in the neck.

Comment: I agree, one thing to do is to write a small script, perl, python whatever, that will take as a commandline parameter the new string and append it to a given strings.xml file. Should be doable in 2 or so hrs. Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

What you refer to is common Localization problem. It is not just strings.xml and Android platform related.

As you might be guessing, people actually found ways to resolve it. Typically, you will send just the English file to translators (translation vendors) and they will update it using [Translation Memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_memory) software.
Or if you are independent Software Developer, you may want to use some crowd-sourcing platform for your translations, like [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/), [BabelZilla](http://www.babelzilla.org/index.php) or [Crowdin](https://crowdin.com/). These platforms also act as Translation Memory, so you won't have to manually synchronize individual language files.